# Why is image corrupted after 2-3 times byte array to image conversion?

Tags: android, jpeg

I am writing bytes to jpg image, but after writing bytes, whenever I am trying to open that image from ES file explorer, image gets corrupted.

Below is the code I am trying:

```
private void overWriteImage() {

    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        fos.write(this.imageBytes);
        fos.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also include `file.getPath()` method.

Comment: i have edited my code , please look that and i m getting image corrupted after many trials of different codes but anything is not working in my case

Comment: Just remove `.getPath()` from code line and try it.

Comment: Means try `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);` .

Comment: @NitinPatel and how this would help? `FileOutputStream(String name)` is calling `FileOutputStream(File)` with  `new File(name)` which means that will not change anything ... seems like Million Monkeys Programming Style

Comment: no still it is not working

Comment: seems like `imageBytes` are not jpeg data

Comment: no i have cross checked my imagebytes[] online , it is perfect. can u give me some reference code for this ??

Comment: Code reference? for what? This code is valid ... the only problem is `imageBytes`

Comment: @chandanipatel  First you can cross check with just make bytearray[] code of `ic_launcher` and convert back into image and check that.

Comment: yes it is working , that means issue is with my bytearray , but i cant understand where is the issue ?

Comment: @chandanipatel Just one more cross check method from image to byte array is generating proper bytes (at application or server side).

Comment: i m getting byte[] properly and image from byte also getting properly

Comment: but whenever i change that byte[] 3-4 time then image gets corrupted , why it is not happening at first time i made change , and corrupt after 3-4 time changes in byte[]

Comment: after adding changes 3-4 time 147 = 1
148 = 1
149 = 1
150 = 1
151 = 1
152 = 1
153 = 1
154 = 1
155 = 1
156 = 1
157 = 1
158 = 1
159 = 1
160 = 1
161 = 1
162 = 1
163 = 1 is padded in byte[] , dont knw why ?? is this creates d problem ?

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think that would happen, but i will try it and replay it. Make sure, you are using same methods like android or other(like encoding base64).

Comment: actually i want to add one byte[] to specific position of another byte array[] , i think this is cause of issue , so i m using byte buffer for this , i think it is replacing bytes of jpg image , but i want to shift bytes right and then at that position i want to write my byte[]

Comment: ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(this.imageBytes);
            buf.position(2);
            buf.put(segmentBytes);
            this.imageBytes = buf.array();    , so i want to write at 2 position , and want to shift image bytes , but i think this is replacing old bytes , so causes error